# Conditional logic in Dockerfile, using --build-arg

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Say I have this:

```
ARG my_user="root"  # my_user => default is "root"
USER $my_user
ENV USER=$my_user
```

All good so far, but now we get here:

```
ENV HOME="/root"
```

is there a way to do something like this:

```
ENV HOME $my_user === "root"? "/root" : "/home/$my_user"
```

Obviously, that's the wrong syntax.

The only solution I can think of is to just use two --build-args, something like this:

```
docker build -t zoom \
    --build-arg my_user="foo"  \
    --build-arg my_home="/home/foo"  \
     .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this directly

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-send-runs-output-to-env-in-dockerfile/16106/3

So you have two alternatives

**Use a shell script at start**

You can use a shell script at the start

```
CMD /start.sh
```

And in your `start.sh` you can have that logic

```
if [ $X == "Y" ]; then
   export X=Y
else
   export X=Z
fi
```

**Create a profile environment variable**

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo "export NAME=TARUN" > /etc/profile.d/myenv.sh
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-lc"]
CMD env
```

And then you when you run it

```
$ docker run test
HOSTNAME=d98d44fa1dc9
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PAGER=less
PS1=\h:\w\$
NAME=TARUN
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
CHARSET=UTF-8
```

> Note: The `SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-lc"]` is quite important here, else the profile will not be loaded
>
> Note2: Instead of `RUN echo "export NAME=TARUN" > /etc/profile.d/myenv.sh` you can also do a `COPY myevn.sh /etc/profile.d/myenv.sh` and have the file be present in your build context

Comment: I am not sure if export works in a subshell like that. I think it will only work with `ENV` command or *maybe*  bash -c "export X=Y"

Comment: In case of profile it is sourced in the environment, and once an environment is exported, any child or exec processed will inherit the same. All above is tested and then only posted

Comment: ok thanks I believe you now. although I dont believe that clicked the upvote question button.